# Create a KeyValuePair<byte, string[]> with Linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm developing a C# library with .NET Framework 4.6.2, Entity Framework 6.1.3 and Repository pattern.

I want to create a `KeyValuePair<byte, string[]>` in a select as follows:

```
Dictionary<string, byte> dict = 
    GetAggregationLevelsNameId(arvatoConnectionString, productionOrderId);

KeyValuePair<byte, string[]>[] codes = null;

List<Data.Code> aCodes =
    repo.SearchFor(c => c.ProductionOrderId == productionOrderId).ToList();

if ((aCodes != null) && (aCodes.Count > 0))
{
    codes =
        aCodes
            .Select(ac => new { ac.Level, ac.Serial })
            .AsEnumerable()
            .Select(ac => new KeyValuePair<byte, string[]>(dict[ac.Level], ac.Serial))
            .ToArray();
}
```

But here `.Select(ac => new KeyValuePair<byte, string[]>(dict[ac.Level], ac.Serial))` I get the following error:

> Cannot convert string to string[].

How can I create a `KeyValuePair<byte, string[]>` in that select?

I want to group all the `ac.Serial` with the same `ac.Level` into a `KeyValuePair`.

`ac` is a struct that I haven't declare it anywhere. I create it here `Select(ac => new { ac.Level, ac.Serial })`.

`ac.Level` is a `string`. 
`ac.Serial` is a `string`.

**UPDATE**:
I have this code that works converting the select into a `Dictionary` (note that the following dictionary has its key as a `string`, not as a `byte` that the one I want to create now):

```
GenericRepository<Data.Code> repo =
    new GenericRepository<Data.Code>(context);

codes =
    repo
        .SearchFor(c => c.ProductionOrderId == productionOrderId)
        .GroupBy(c => c.Level)
        .ToDictionary(dic => dic.Key, dic => dic.Select(c => c.Serial).ToList());
```

**UPDATE 2**:
The `Data.Code` is a POCO object that represents a Database table where there are a lot of `Serial` with the same `Level`.

Comment: I'm too lazy to go through all the types but the error message implies that `ac.Serial` is a `string` and you need a `string[]`; in that case `.Select(ac => new KeyValuePair<byte, string[]>(dict[ac.Serial], new string[] { ac.Serial }))` should work.

Comment: In your code, what is type of ac.Serial ?

If possible, could you post ac Class structure?

Comment: @VansFannel, Your serial property is type of string.

Then why you want to return string array?

What data are you expecting in string array?

Comment: Can you provide some samples of the input data in each object, and the desired output object? What relevance does `dict[]` have to this, since Level is already a byte? I felt I undersotod your question but now I don't.

Comment: @john Sorry, you are right. `ac.Level` is a `string`.

Comment: @AshishSapkale I want to return a `string[]` of Serial grouped by `ac.Level`. The `Data.Code` is a POCO object that represents a Database table where there are a lot of `Serial` with the same `Level`.

Comment: So is the key for "dict" ac.Serial, or ac.Level?

Comment: @john Sorry, I have corrected the error in the question. The key is `ac.Level`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
codes =
    aCodes
        .AsEnumerable()
        .GroupBy(ac => dict[ac.Level])
        .Select(ac => new KeyValuePair<byte, string[]>(ac.Key, ac.Select(a => a.Serial).ToArray()))
        .ToArray();
```

Or to a dictionary:

```
codes =
    aCodes
        .AsEnumerable()
        .GroupBy(ac => dict[ac.Level])
        .ToDictionary(ac => ac.Key, ac.ToArray());
```

Comment: I have edit your question with the right answer. Thanks a lot for your time and support.